# Suppress author field when printing shorthands with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I want to print a list of shorthands of the cited literature. This list will be part of the frontmatter, and all of the references in this list will be from the same author. As the complete details of the references will also be included in the bibliography at the end of the document, I would like to suppress the author in this shorthand list.

Is it possible to suppress certain fields when printing the shorthands OR, conversely, is it possible to specify which fields should be printed in this list? I do not want to change any settings that would also affect the bibliography at the end of the document.

Here is the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book {gramsci1971,
author = {Gramsci, Antonio},
title = {Selections from the Prison Notebooks},
location = {London},
year = {1971},
translator = {Hoare, Quintin and Smith, Geoffrey Nowell},
editor = {Hoare, Quintin and Smith, Geoffrey Nowell},
publisher = {Lawrence \& Wishart},
shorthand = {SPN}
}

@book {gramsci1995,
author = {Gramsci, Antonio},
title = {Further Selections from the Prison Notebooks},
location = {London},
year = {1995},
translator = {Boothman, Derek},
editor = {Boothman, Derek},
publisher = {Lawrence \& Wishart},
shorthand = {FS}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authoryear, autocite=inline, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text with a citation \autocite[12]{gramsci1971}, and some further text with another citation \autocite[353]{gramsci1995}.

\printbiblist[title={Works cited by Antonio Gramsci}, sorting=ynt]{shorthand}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the `shorthand` driver

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorthand}{%
  \usedriver
    {\clearname{author}\def\do##1{\togglefalse{blx@use##1}}\abx@donames}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
  \finentry}
\makeatother
```

or even make it more compact

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorthand}{%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printdate
  \finentry}
```

of course this can be completely customised.

---

Alternatively, you can modify the automatically created `shorthand` bibenvironment to forget the `author` and not print the editor in her stead

```
\makeatletter
  \defbibenvironment{shorthand}
   {\list{\thefield{shorthand}}{%
       \labelwidth\csname shorthandwidth\endcsname
       \labelsep\biblabelsep
       \leftmargin\labelwidth
       \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
       \itemsep\bibitemsep
       \parsep\bibparsep
       \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
    {\endlist}
    {\clearname{author}\def\do##1{\togglefalse{blx@use##1}}\abx@donames\item}
\makeatother
```